# Copy Single Row To Another Sheet VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why I am having the hardest time with this. I am just trying to copy a single row from sheet1 to the next available row on sheet2. I have to row copied but it just wont paste without giving me error. This is my copy and it is working.

```
ws1.Rows(j).EntireRow.Copy
```

Comment: what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Im going through a loop and if I found the item I am looking for then I will copy it to another sheet.

Comment: What error are you getting while pasting?

Answer (score 10):

Following should be helpful

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, j As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To 10 'change loop as required
        If (your_condition) Then
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            ws1.Rows(j).EntireRow.Copy ws2.Range("A" & lastRow)
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: how does `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` know to look in the `Sheet2`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Code Sample:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below code

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Sheet1.Range("A:A").Copy

Sheet2.Activate
col = 1
Do Until Sheet2.Cells(1, col) = ""
    col = col + 1
Loop

Sheet2.Cells(1, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: This is **(a)** bad practise, you should avoid using `Activate` when possible, and it achieves nothing here anyway, **(b)** not a quick or "safe" way to find the next empty cell in a column, **(c)** you're copying columns not rows, like the OP asked, and pasting just values which isn't necessarily desirable either, in that case you'd be better just using the `.Value = .Value` method